# How to convert a string var to hex in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, mac-address

i have a string `"aa2a.aaa2.aaaa"`. I want to pass this as a string parameter but this should be converted to mac address using some hex conversion method. How can i convert the string into hex?

```
hex(mac)
```

Above method wont help as it will just convert the string into its hex value.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: Why dots in between?

Comment: Do you want to get `'aa:2a:aa:a2:aa:aa'`? e.g., `s = "aa2a.aaa2.aaaa".replace('.', '');` `mac = ":".join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))`

Answer (score 2):

You can not apply the `hex` on your string because it contains the dot characters you can split it by dot and convert them to an int with base 16 then convert to hex :

```
>>> s="aa2a.aaa2.aaaa"
>>> '.'.join(map(lambda x:hex(int(x,16)),s.split('.')))
'0xaa2a.0xaaa2.0xaaaa'
```

Or if you are sure that all the literal are valid base 16 you can simply do :

```
>>> s="aa2a.aaa2.aaaa"
>>> '.'.join(map(lambda i:'0x{}'.format(i),s.split('.')))
'0xaa2a.0xaaa2.0xaaaa'
```

If it wasn't so the first solution will raise a `ValueError` which you can handle it with an exception.